# Sharepoint List Permissions - how to prevent opening attachments?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

My Sharepoint "View Only" permission group is described as "Allows users to see a document/item exists, but cannot open any documents/items."

That description describes the behavior I want. I have a list where the visible columns display information that I'd like to be visible to anyone, but I only want the attachments to be accessible to people assigned to the item.

The trouble is that members in the group I assigned "View Only" permissions can still not only open the item, but open and download the attachments.

When I investigate the permission group, the List Permissions that are checked include only: View Items, View Versions, Create Alerts, View Application Pages.

I don't have permissions to modify or create a Permissions group myself, but could ask someone to do it for me.

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, if the user can view item in the list, they can open item attachment. It's by default.

So, there is no option to make the user can view item but cannot open item attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Users with View only or Read permissions can see/open the list item attachments. This is a default behavior in SharePoint.

You cannot change this behavior in SharePoint. However, you can restrict users from downloading the attachments.

For more information related to this, check my answer at: [How to add users to the Viewer role in a communications site to prevent the ability to download files?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304900/how-to-add-users-to-the-viewer-role-in-a-communications-site-to-prevent-the-abil)